# cssのmargin,paddingなど、要素の位置を指定することができない原因がわかりません

Tags: html, css

htmlを

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <title>margin test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <a href="#">要素1</a>
        <a href="#">要素2</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

のようにし、cssを

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
html,
body{
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
h1{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'arial';
    cursor: pointer;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'arial';
    color: #333;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    right: 1%;
    left: 1%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.panel > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'arial';
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
.panel > a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #333;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
```

のようにしたときに、margin-top,padding-top,top等が効かない原因がわかりません
また、aの要素を縦並びにする方法も知りたいです

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

＞amargin,padding,top等が効かない原因がわかりません

ご提示いただいたファイルでテストしてみましたが
a要素にmarginとpaddingは効きました。
css自体は反映されていますでしょうか。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
```

こちらのhrefという値をご確認ください。
htmlとtest.cssが同じフォルダ内にあれば上記指定で大丈夫ですが
さらに別のフォルダ内にcssが置いてある場合はパスが違っています。

回答の認識が違っていましたら詳しい状況を教えてください。

---

aの要素を縦ならびにする方法ですが
縦のメニューなどによく使われるパターンとして

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">要素１</a></li>
    <li><a href="">要素２</a></li>
</ul>
```

というものがあります。

htmlのタグはinline要素とblock要素というのがあり
横に並ぶか縦に並ぶかなどの特性が変わってきます。
http://www.htmq.com/htmlkihon/005.shtml
また上記のような特性だけでなく
タグごとに使用用途が提示されているので
タグを正確に使うことも重要だと言われます。

Comment: margin-topやmargin-bottomが効かないのですが、原因は分かりますでしょうか？

Comment: aタグにmargin-topが効かないということで合っていますでしょうか。
↑こちらを前提に回答しますと
下記ページに詳細がありました。
http://markup.webcrew.co.jp/art_20141023.html

aタグはインライン要素という部類になるので
効かないということですね。

これを力技で強制するときは
a{
display: block;
margin-top: 30px;
}
などとするといけると思います。